# for loop over a list

Tags: bash, for

I have a small script which should print a couple of calls to a makefile i got.

```
mylist='$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17) $(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18) $(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19) $(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20) $(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21) $(call list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22) $(call list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23) $(call list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)'

for SAMPLES_OUT in $mylist;
do
echo "$SAMPLES_OUT"
done
```

Output:

```
$(call
list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)
$(call
list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)
$(call
list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)
$(call
list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)
$(call
list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21)
$(call
list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22)
$(call
list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23)
$(call
list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)
```

the problem i am experiencing is that the for loop is splitting on spaces and therefor the $call and list_samples are taken apart while they should be actually one call. like this:

```
$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)
$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)
$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)
$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)
$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21)
$(call list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22)
$(call list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23)
$(call list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)
```

I have tried putting the strings in "" but that does not work since it is a list created with '' it sees everything between that as a string. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Found this link which might be helpful - http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

Comment: @rahul Thanks for the tip, but after trying and reading it still doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array to keep the elements together:

```
mylist=(
    '$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)'
)
for SAMPLES_OUT in "${mylist[@]}"    # crucial to use quotes here
do
    echo "$SAMPLES_OUT"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a different separator from the default (the default being space, tab and newline):

```
mylist='
$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17) 
$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18) 
$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19) 
$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20) 
$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21) 
$(call list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22) 
$(call list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23) 
$(call list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)
'

IFS='
'       # split on newline only
set -f  # disable globbing
for samples_out in $mylist # invoke the split+glob operator
do
  printf '%s\n' "$samples_out"
done
```

That way, you can keep using standard `sh` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the problem might be that you're including so much static data in your variable definition. It looks to me like your actual variable data is just a simple set of three numbers, each of which is incremented by one per iteration. The rest is just dressing. So maybe...

```
 pr_samples()( 
     for n in lmt AON NT SC
     do  : "$(($n=(${1##*[!-0-9]*}0/10)-1))"
            shift "$((!!$#))"
     done;  lmt=$((lmt+AON+1))
     until [ "$AON" -gt "$lmt" ]
     do    printf '$(call list_samples,AON_%d,NT_%d,SC_%d)\n' \
                  "$((AON+=1))" "$((NT+=1))" "$((SC+=1))"
     done
)
```

...which would build out your set if called like:

```
 pr_samples 7 9 1 17
```

...where the first argument is the iteration count and the next three are the initial values for `$AON`, `$NT`, and `$SC` respectively. A null value argument is interpreted as a zero.

Anyway, called as above, it prints:

```
$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)
$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)
$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)
$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)
$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21)
$(call list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22)
$(call list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23)
$(call list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)
```

It could be useful to pass the `printf` format string as an argument as well.