# Make does not work when invoked from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, make

So i just asked a question : [for loop over a list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184681/for-loop-over-a-list)

This works perfectly now and outputs what i need. Now i want to link this to a makefile which should be called per variable in my list like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mylist=(
    '$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_13,NT_5,SC_21)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_14,NT_6,SC_22)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_15,NT_7,SC_23)'
    '$(call list_samples,AON_16,NT_8,SC_24)'
)



for SAMPLES_out in "${mylist[@]}";
do
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT=\'${SAMPLES_out}\'
done
```

This give me a make error: `` make_gene_read_count.mk:5: *** unterminated call to function `call': missing `)'.  Stop. ``

While if i put echo in front of the call to make in my bash script it prints them out like this:

```
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT='$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)'
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT='$(call list_samples,AON_10,NT_2,SC_18)'
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT='$(call list_samples,AON_11,NT_3,SC_19)'
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT='$(call list_samples,AON_12,NT_4,SC_20)'
```

If i add one of those echos to the commandline the makefile works perfectly. What am i missing?

This is the makefile:

```
IN_DIR = /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/namesorted_bams
list_samples = $(shell ls $(IN_DIR)/*$(1)* $(IN_DIR)/*$(2)* $(IN_DIR)/*$(3)* | sed 's/\.namesorted\.bam/\.gene\.read\.count/g')
#SAMPLES_OUT := $(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)

all: $(SAMPLES_OUT)

GFF := /data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1.gff
GFF_TEMP := $(GFF).temp.gff

$(GFF_TEMP): $(GFF)
    sed 's/\*/./g' $< > $@

%.gene.read.count: %.namesorted.bam $(GFF_TEMP)
    htseq-count -t exon -m intersection-strict -f bam -r name -s no $^ > $@
```

I am also trying to pass 2 variables to my makefile but this does not seem to work properly as well if I do it like this in my bash scripts list:

```
'$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1‌​.gff'
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
qmake: *** No rule to make target `GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1.gff', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want the single quotes to get propagated to the makefile. Don't quote them, and replace them with double quotes - that would keep the variable value as one word in the shell.

```
make -f make_gene_read_count.mk -n SAMPLES_OUT="$SAMPLES_out"
```

If you want to pass more variables, separate them by unquoted whitespace:

```
make VAR1="some value containing $val" VAR2='some other value'
#                                     ^
```

Comment: thanks, i was really confused by this. Strange is that if i try to run the makefile on command line and it is not between ' ' it will not work, so therefor i thought that this is also the case while running from bash script.

Comment: I have one more question to you can you tell what would happen if i want for example another variable passed to the make file like this: '$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17) GFF=/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1.gff'

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Questions in comments aren't readable.

Comment: Ooh sure sorry ill add it to my question @choroba It should be in the question now ;) thanks for helping me out

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Check the update.

Comment: If i do it like that it means i am back to the old problem where the for loop is splitting the 2 in seperate lines. Can you give a working example from the bash file I now have it like this: 
` mylist=(
    'SAMPLES_OUT='$(call list_samples,AON_9,NT_1,SC_17)' GFF='/data/DIV5/SASC/project-013-motor/analysis/runs/BWA_chipcap/BAMS/GFF/H3K4me1.gff''
`

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Oh, you want to store the pairs of values in the array?

Comment: yes indeed, sorry for my late response was away in the weekend :). If i need to seperate these 2 values i need to create 2 for loops in my bash script and i want to avoid that. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: You should probably start a new question, as asking for several different things in one question is confusing (as we've well demonstrated) and prevents people knowing the answer to only some of them from answering.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will start a new question when i have some time.